# ResourceFunction memory leak?

Tags: bugs, memory, resourcefunction

**Bug introduced in 12.3 or earlier and persisting through 12.3.1 or later**

`ResourceFunction` seems to cause a substantial memory leak when called many times.

e.g. to observe, try

```
PrintTemporary[Dynamic[Refresh[MemoryInUse[], UpdateInterval -> 1]]];
TimeConstrained[
  While[True, 
   ResourceFunction["SCombinatorHaltsQ"][CombinatorS[CombinatorS]]], 
  10];
```

or

```
PrintTemporary[Dynamic[Refresh[MemoryInUse[], UpdateInterval -> 1]]];
TimeConstrained[
  While[True, 
   ResourceFunction[
     "NestedLookup"][<|"Flintstones" -> <|"Fred" -> <|"Job" -> 
          "Bronto crane Operator"|>, 
       "Wilma" -> <|"Job" -> "Cavemaker"|>, 
       "Pebbles" -> <|"Job" -> "Child"|>|>|>, {"Flintstones", "Fred", 
     "Job"}]], 10];
```

Can anyone confirm this is a bug, or am I misusing `ResourceFunction` in some way?

Comment: I think this is worth reporting to support as a bug. As a workaround, you can do ``Remove["ResourceSystemClientDump`$*"]`` to recover the memory.